# SideMenu Warning: attempt to push a View Controller from where its navigationController == nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, uinavigationcontroller, side-menu

I have added `jonkykong/SideMenu` pod in my project. if I am adding viewcontrollers in sidemenu then it is working fine.

Given segue present modelly from all sidemenubutton in viewcontroller to UISideMenuNavigationController

If I add all viewControllers in sidemenu then its working fine but if I go **like below :**

`UISideMenuNavigationController -> home(is a collectionview) -> MakePaymentViewController -> PaymentOptionsViewController`

**in home deselect:**

```
let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakePaymentViewController") as? MakePaymentViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController!, animated: true)
```

**In MakePaymentViewController makePaymentButton:**

```
let makepayVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakePaymenyOptionsViewController") as! MakePaymenyOptionsViewController
makepayVC.amounText = totalAmount
self.present(makepayVC, animated: true)
```

and if I give segue present modelly from MakePaymenyOptionsViewController's sidemenu button to UISideMenuNavigationController then I am getting below error

I don't want MakePaymenyOptionsViewController in sidemenu.

> SideMenu Warning: attempt to push a View Controller from Optional() where its navigationController == nil. It must be embedded in a Navigation Controller for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

`MakePaymenyOptionsViewController` must be embedded in a NavigationController in order this to work.

Comment: i dont want MakePaymenyOptionsViewController in side menu this is separate viewcontoller.. but it has sidemenu button